# "This project is empty" error in Sonarqube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have configured a C# project in Sonarqube. After analysis is done, I can see the below screen on the dashboard for the project "CsprojFromCs".

[image: Dashboard]

When I click on the project name and go to the details page, it shows me "This project is empty" as below.

[image: Error Message]

My C# project contains two files and I am able to run it correctly. Why is it showing "This project is empty" in the overview tab?

Below is the snapshot of the analysis.

1."C:\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:"CsprojFromCs" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="e1295f619c7ff6f08f974f5a18141b999e830610"

Output:

[image]

2.Command:  MsBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

Output:
 [image]

3.Command:
"C:\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" end /d:sonar.login="e1295f619c7ff6f08f974f5a18141b999e830610"

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the analysis?

Comment: @JeroenHeier: I have added the output along with the corresponding commands.It doesn't report any error as such on the console as of now.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? I have the same.

Comment: @AlekseyKornienko, sorry but I was not able to solve this and could not try much at that time.

Comment: I have the same problem here. The analysis seems to run fine on the prompt but on the sonarQube I don't see any results, even with my code with a lot of smell code. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the SCM plugin wrongly ignore all the files. Disabling the SCP plugin solves the issue.

To disable SCP use `sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true` analysis parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by scan csproj instead of sln :) My sln contains multiple projects and sonar can't scan them together

Comment: Thanks for this info.I remember, I was not getting this error for the solution having multiple projects. It was just for a solution having only one project of type console.Also it was strange to see other type project like MVC template where it did work but there were auto generated multiple files. I did try to add multiple file in my console project but that also did not work.

Comment: I also tried it but no results. I still can see any results on the sonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues, solved by adding below contents in pom.xml.

```
  </properties>
    .....
      <sonar.sources>src/</sonar.sources>
  </properties>
```